# Generate an MPDF to PDF with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, mpdf

This the my code a CV that I want to create an MPDF with and underneath I have the MPDF code that is on another page. The content is appearing on the pdf but with php echo values when i want the actual php values instead

```
<?php
            //Image upload
            $uploaddir = "images\\";
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $userTime . basename($_FILES['myimg']['name']); 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myimg"]["tmp_name"], "$uploadfile");
            $_SESSION['myimg'] = $uploadfile;

            if(isset($_FILES['myimg'])){
                $file = $_FILES['myimg']['name'];
                //echo "" .$file;
                //echo "<img src='" . $file . "'>";
                echo '<img src="' . $uploadfile . '" width="40%" height="40% "/>'; 
            }
        ?>
        <p>First Name<br><?php echo $fullName;?></p> 
        <p>Email Address<br><?php echo $emailAddress;?></p>
        <p>Phone Number<br><?php echo $phoneNumber;?></p>`enter code here`
        <p>College<br><?php echo $theEducation;?></p>
        <p>Course<br><?php echo $theCourse;?></p>

<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

    // $mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('build.php'));

    $mpdf->Output();
    //$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either build your HTML content to a string:

```
$html = '';
...
$html .= '<img src="' . $uploadfile . '" width="40%" height="40% "/>'
$html .= '<p>First Name<br>' . $fullName . '</p> 
<p>Email Address<br>' . $emailAddress . '</p>
<p>Phone Number<br>' . $phoneNumber . '</p>
<p>College<br>' . $theEducation . '</p>
<p>Course<br>' . $theCourse . '</p>';
```

Or use [output buffering](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the html.

Then, pass the HTML to mPDF:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```